# Less CSS: Can I call a mixin as an argument when calling another mixin?

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

I'm trying to call a mixin as an argument in another mixin but I get a syntax error. There's no variables in the offending mixin call, just arguments.

I'm not sure if this is possible. The answers I've seen on here seem to be either hacks or to be dealing with variables and strings as arguments.

Less CSS

```
// color variables for user's color
@userColor: #13acae;
@darkUser: hsl(hue(@userColor), saturation(@userColor), lightness(tint(@userColor, 30%)));
@lightUser: hsl(hue(@userColor), saturation(@userColor), lightness(shade(@userColor, 30%)));

// color mixin to alter user's color using Less 'darken' and 'contrast' functions
.contrastColorDark(@percent) { color: darken(contrast(@userColor, @darkUser, @lightUser), @percent); }

// border mixin
.border(@width, @color) { border: @width solid @color; }

// CSS rule using both mixins
.thing {
    .border(1px, .contrastColorDark(10%));
}
```

Error (at the dot before `.contrastColorDark(10%)` )

```
SyntaxError: expected ')' got '.'
```

**What I am trying to achieve:** I am trying to get the box border color to match certain elements inside it that are using the contrast mixin.

Comment: Nope you can't do it this way. Less mixins are not functions and they don't return any value.

Comment: ahh ok that explains it perfectly. thank you :)

Comment: But maybe there is a different way to get what you need. Can you let me know the actual problem and expected output? For example, you could still call the mixin and then pass its output value as a parameter (a bit different in syntax).

Comment: [This](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/qOayJj?editors=010) is an example of what I meant.

Comment: that definitely does what i wanted: the box border color to match certain elements inside it that are using the contrast mixin.

Comment: Check out Sass. As I understand it, you can use sass as a programming language and do these more complex functions.

Comment: See `functions` [plugin](http://lesscss.org/usage/#plugins-list-of-less-plugins).

Comment: @Jeannie: I have added that solution as an answer. Also have a look at the functions plugin suggested by seven-phases-max.

Comment: @Harry thank you, that's a great explanation. i've accepted it.

Comment: @seven-phases-max very nice plugin, i can see a lot of use in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments, Less mixins are not functions and the mixin calls cannot return any value. Because of this, one mixin (or its output value) cannot be passed as an argument to another mixin.

Having said that, we can still set a variable within a mixin, call the mixin within each selector block where it is required and make use of the variable defined within it. The mixin call effectively exposes the variable defined within it to the parent scope.

Below is a sample snippet which would call the contrast mixin and assign the calculated value as the text color and border color of the element.

```css
// color variables for user's color
@userColor: #13acae;
@darkUser: hsl(hue(@userColor), saturation(@userColor), lightness(tint(@userColor, 30%)));
@lightUser: hsl(hue(@userColor), saturation(@userColor), lightness(shade(@userColor, 30%)));

// color mixin to alter user's color using Less 'darken' and 'contrast' functions
.contrastColorDark(@percent) { 
    @color: darken(contrast(@userColor, @darkUser, @lightUser), @percent); 
    //color: darken(contrast(@userColor, @darkUser, @lightUser), @percent);  
 }

// border mixin
.border(@width, @color) { 
    border: @width solid @color; 
}

// CSS rule using both mixins
.thing {
    .contrastColorDark(10%);
    color: @color;
    .border(1px, @color);
}

.thing2 {
    .contrastColorDark(50%);
    color: @color;
    .border(1px, @color);
}
```