# Pass mixin as mixin param in LESS

Tags: css, less

I have the the following mixin:

```
.image-ui-wave-pos (@num, @selected:0) when (@selected = 0) {
    background-position: -(@image-ui-wave-width * @num) -28px;
}
```

I'd like to pass it to the following mixin as parameter:

```
.small-button (@pos-macro, @buttons, @i) when (@i > 0) {
    @button: extract(@buttons, @i);

    &.@{button} {
        .pos-macro (@i);
    }

    .small-button(@pos-macro, @buttons, @i - 1);
}
```

as the parameter @pos-macro calling it like this:

```
.small-button (.image-ui-wave-pos, @wave-buttons);
```

But it doesn't compile. How to do so?

Comment: No, you cannot pass a mixin as argument to another mixin in Less. You may find this thread helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766850/less-css-can-i-call-a-mixin-as-an-argument-when-calling-another-mixin though it won't give you a direct solution.